# UIWebView scalesPageToFit won't scale page

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that, despite having scalesPageToFit set to YES, doesn't perform any such scaling operation: The web page starts off zoomed in and it's necessary to unpinch to get the whole thing on the page.

What could prevent UIWebView::scalesPageToFit from being honored?

Comment: How do you set up this UIWebView? Do you set scalesPageToFit before or after loading page?

Comment: I set scalePageToFit immediately after initializing the UIWebView, in the ViewDidLoad method of the parent view.

Answer (score 3):

You could inject the viewport element via JavaScript.

Look for the `viewport` meta tag here: [Safari Meta Tags](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=2.3, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: and mine day too :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a file in your project named changePageWidth.js:

```
function changePageWidth(width) {
  var element = document.createElement('meta');
  element.name = "viewport";
  element.content = "width=" + width;
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  head.appendChild(element);
}
```

and then add this code in webViewDidFinishLoad: of UIWebView's delegate:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"changePageWidth" ofType:@"js"];
    NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];
    NSString *jsCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"changePageWidth(%d)", webView.frame.size.width];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCall];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use java script to resize your browser

```
NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = 1.5;"];
webLookupView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
```