# while opening in safari, make safari as safari.scalesPageToFit = NO;

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile-safari

I have button as "Open In Safari". On clicking this button, same button get opened in safari in iPhone app.

However for UIWebView I have,

```
 myWebView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
```

**I want to apply SAME for safari too.**

I am saying bcz the page looks ugly in safari when I have not applied scalesPageToFit.

Any idea how to get this done?

---

### Answer

Below line in html file did the trick.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
```

[**Reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9435205/1066828)

Comment: Probably might be better to post the solution as an answer to the question

Comment: @gtmtg : If I do like that, moderator delete that answer...

Comment: Ah, that's fine. Did they give a reason? I just suggested that so that the question wouldn't appear unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below line in html file did the trick.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
```

[**Reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9435205/1066828)